# Query Regarding Copying local folder jar in Lib folder using Maven

Tags: java, maven

As we do in Ant build, we can specify the Jars that we need to copy in build.xml in case of Ant(We just need to specify the folder name from which we need to pick the jar files). Is there any facility of same kind is available in Maven as well.

If yes, Then do we need to add the dependency tags equal to the number of jars in folder or one dependency tag is sufficient. I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your missing the point of dependency management. All the JAR's required by your project should be defined as dependencies in your POM. If you have any custom JAR files (not available in a public repo) then you will want to install those in a local repository, and access them that way.

Comment: Do I need to write the dependency tag that many number of times equal to my number of jars.

Comment: Yes, you define a dependency for each library your project depends on. Note that you should only declare dependencies you *really* need. Because the act of pulling one library into your project can cause several others to be downloaded (which is one of the benefits of Maven, you don't have to keep track of all that stuff yourself).